# Changing the color of the status bar when I'm calling from my application

Tags: ios, swift

I'm setting navigation bar and status bar.

```
static func setParamsBars(){
    let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = .clear

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Regular", size: 18)!]

    let imagebar : UIImage = UIImage(color: UIColor(red: 136.0/255.0, green: 136.0/255.0, blue: 136.0/255.0, alpha: 0.8), size: CGSize(width: bounds.size.width, height: 84))!
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(imagebar, for: .default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
}
```

and call this function in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

my first screen [image]

I call phone number [image]

Then when I return to the application the status bar changes color
[image]

Then I added the following code. insure:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    AppEventsLogger.activate(application)

    print("applicationDidBecomeActive")
    //AppDelegate.setParamsBars()
    //UINavigationBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = false
    //UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = .clear

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try extending UIApplication as below:

(And you can change it with every `ViewController`)

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
return .lightContent
}
```

Comment: so you're saying , we can change color of `statusBar` as we please(I mean other then `.default` or `.dark`) ..... I've used that but didn't know that it can also be of `red` color , Can you explain it more please ???

Comment: Check again above code, Its edited now and you can change accordingly light or dark

Comment: Okay, I already upvoted it yesterday as I was unsure of that ,now I'm sure that it can only be changed `light` or `dark`...